# Dictionary comprehension - dynamically generate key-value pairs?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I want to achieve the same result of

```py
{i: i+1 for i in range(4)} # {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

But dynamically generate `key: value` part with `myfunc(i)`, how do I do that?

Functions that return `{i: i+1}` or `(i, i+1)` won't work:

```py
{{i: i+1} for i in range(4)} # TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Can you explain more?

Comment: `{{i: i+1} for i in range(4)}` doesn't work because it's a _set_ comprehension and you're trying to make a set of single-key-value-pair dicts. Dicts are not hashable, so you can't have a set of dicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict(map(myfunc, range(4)))
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Example:

```
>>> dict([(1,2), (3,4)])
{1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> dict(map(lambda x: (x, x+1), range(4)))
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following comprehension script doesn't work because you are using a dictionary as a key.

```
{{i: i+1} for i in range(4)} # TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

this is like this:

```
a = {1:2}
b = {a:3} # TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The point is that all dictionary keys should be from immutable data types like Strings, Numbers, Tuples or Frozen Sets. In other word, you **can not use** mutable data types like Dictionaries, List or Sets as Dictionary key or a even Set value.

Comment: "you are using a dictionary as a key" that comprehension actually creates a _set_, not a dictionary, and the problem is that elements of a set must be hashable, but dictionaries aren't